# How to query multiple where in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have a query that gets all the message between two id (user_id and to_user_id). I want to select all the query all the message of user in the two tables.

I have already made two where and it doesn't seem to work. It is just returning null.

```
  $last_message = DB::table('messages')
                  ->select('content')
                  ->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
                  ->where('to_user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
                  ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                  ->first();
```

I expect the output of all the message of user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check on this ***Auth::user()->id***, 
to see if it has a value or not. Also check on the datatype between table field and data source in query builder.